# Can we have a way to earn greater review queue privileges?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

I understand that the review queue was lowered to 20 reviews a day to prevent "serial approvers" and the like from doing too much damage in one go, and also to remove some of the inventive for doing this just to earn a quick badge.  However, there are those of us who do actually try to read the questions/answers and really effect some quality in the community.

Is there some judgment or criteria we can use to give those people who are actually putting time and thought into it more opportunity to review and raise that limit?  Perhaps if the user spends greater than five or ten seconds on most of his reviews ("most" being 80%? 90%?) then that qualifies him for a greater share.

I know that "time spent" isn't always an indication of quality, and I understand that this can still be gamed by just waiting around, but most badge-mongers will still just take their 20 for the day and be done, and the ones who stick around and wait fall under one of two categories: either they'll be bored for those five/ten seconds and actually glance at the post in question, or they are the kind of obsessive person who won't be deterred no matter what policy you have in place.

Comment: If you spend more than 10 seconds, the queue will be empty again, and there will be no use for any extra review privileges. I used to do lots of edit reviews when the queue was full, now there is nothing to look at.

Comment: @BoPersson Hm, that's true.  I didn't think of that.  But at least the people taking time would get to continue to take their time all day, rather than taking their time on just 20 and then being locked out just like your average badge-farmer.

Comment: It's the flags queue that needs all the help it can get...

Comment: @BoPersson For a practical example, I've hit my 20 reviews for the day on Suggested Edits.  I do actually take my time to look at them, even if it means the queue after it is empty or close to empty.  Now I'm locked out and I can't do anything else, and the spot is left open for one more serial-approver.  Haha

Comment: @Oded Do users get a badge for helping out in the 10k flag queue?

Comment: @BilltheLizard - I believe there are no badges associated with it (apart from those for raising flags).

Comment: I made a similar post - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157354/suggested-edits-after-limit-of-20-runs-out-how-to-proceed - but that was mostly frustration about being "locked out" of edits until something cleared the queue. So, now I don't bother so much, and just leave it so I can still vote in/out good/bad edits for tags I'm interested in...

Comment: Interesting idea, but instead of "time taken to review" maybe a better indicator would be passing/failing honeypot queue items. If you keep passing those tests, why limit the number of items a user can review? Personally I'd like more close votes for that queue (considering there are 49k items in that queue maybe it's even more applicable there)

Comment: greater review privileges should be given to 1) those who already have gold badge (ie lack incentive to game for it) and 2) in queues that are in the need for more reviewing. I for one find it f#$%ng de-motivating that Close Votes count sits at about same f#$%ng ~50K items day by day, week by week while I am doing my tiny 20 items/day there. Feels like total waste, taking teaspoon of water from an ocean

Comment: @gnat: It is dropping, on average. Slowly. A few weeks ago it was well over 50k, now it's dropping under 50k. It might be empty in 8 months or so! I do 40 reviews there most days, despite being long past the gold badge.

Comment: YES YES YES YES YES

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently most all of the review queues are perpetually sitting at empty, or close to empty.  There are so many people trying to review and not enough posts to satisfy the review ability.  That's why the limit was put in place to begin with.  It's not even entirely to limit the potential damage of those abusing the system (although that's a nice benefit as well).  Many of the problems in the queue are a result of too many people trying to review a post at the same time (people editing over each other, posts being approved/rejected while someone else is editing, posts being otherwise acted on while someone is still reading through the post and looking for what needs work, etc.).

By putting some limits on how much people can review it can help the queues get a little bit above empty for longer, and simply allow people to participate without needing to review items in less than 5 seconds to have it take effect.

The bottom line is that the current limit is A Good Thing even for people reviewing properly.

If you really like reviewing, and feel you are a valuable reviewer, you can also spend time reviewing posts outside of the review queues.  You don't *need* to be in a queue to help improve the site.  [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155573/186381) is another post in which I list some possible ways of helping to improve the site and review content outside of the official review queues.

Comment: ...with the notable exception of the close votes queue, which will continue to have thousands of questions for the foreseeable future, and which I *can't* review more of outside of the queue. I have to ration my supply of daily close votes as it is if I want to get through the low quality and new post queues as well as the close votes. I used to look at the close votes list in the 10k tools on a regular basis; these days I don't even bother.

Answer (score 3):

## Bad idea

Before the 20 review limit, I spend too much time reviewing. The 20 limit saved my life outside of Stack Exchange.

Comment: So if SE staff ever need to assassinate you for some reason, now they know how to do it!

Comment: But the said "we come in peace"...    drat did I really fell for that old trick.