# Remove 20 reviews per day for people who gained gold badge for that review type

Tags: feature-request, review, rate-limiting

I realize that the 20 reviews per user per day limitation is to prevent gaming the system into awarding badges (That limitation fails miserably by the way, but that's not the topic of discussion).

I have already reached the Steward badge for Suggested Edits review. Can I please get this silly limitation lifted from me? I think I've proven (by continuing to submit reviews even after the gold badge) that I don't intend to game the system with crap reviews, but genuinely review for quality control.

So can we please lift that limitation for people with over 1000 reviews in their respective review types?

Comment: What makes you think that crap reviewers stop reviewing once they hit 1k?

Comment: @benisuqbackwards: Because that's when they get the badge. What other reason would they have for posting crap reviews?

Comment: If that is their only goal, yes. But there are a bunch of poor reviewers I encounter on a daily basis who must think that they are doing a good job reviewing and are being helpful. Even though they already have their badge.

Comment: @Bart: In that case, a different system to differentiate those from the good reviewers is in order. But again, that's not the subject of discussion.

Comment: It might not be the subject of discussion, but it means that your statement (The point is that they quit after reaching 1k) does not necessarily hold ground either.

Comment: @Bart: The assumption I'm making is that users with a proven record of good judgement should have a higher limitation, where users without such proof will have a lower one. Be it via number of points you have, or some other system. I find it very annoying to not be able to contribute to the quality control after reviewing for not more than 10 minutes!

Comment: @MadaraUchiha There are more than enough other tasks you can perform after that which would significantly improve the quality of the site.

Comment: So, uh. If you game the system to get the gold badge, you have good judgement?

Comment: @J.Steen: No, but if you continue to review after reaching 1k, you seemingly have good judgement.

Comment: While I happen to disagree with that particular statement - one only shows good judgement in that one realises that reviewing is good, one is not necessarily performing good reviews - I was merely pointing out the interesting fallacy of assuming that people who a) got a gold badge and b) keep reviewing show good judgement.

Comment: Man, I repeated myself a lot, there.

Comment: Related maybe dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159881/can-we-have-a-way-to-earn-greater-review-queue-privileges

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The limit is not just there to prevent crap reviewers from flooding the system. It's there to give everyone a chance to review.

If a number of people have unlimited reviews in a day, noone else gets to have a look-in, and that's not fair.

And crap reviewers make it to 1k reviews faster than those that take reviewing seriously. It's easier to hit 'Looks Good' than to actually *look* at the post.

Last but not least; the badge is a nice 'thank you' gesture for doing all that work. It should not be seen as a certificate of reviewing ability. At most it could  be interpreted as a certificate of tenacity; you have proven that you can continue to review, day after day, even though there is a daily cap on how many reviews you can do. So, you have shown you can live and work with that limit, no reason to lift it now that you got so good at it!

Comment: Well, I for instance, reached the limitation within 10 minutes. a 20 per day is not realistic for [so], and it's just annoying rather than helpful.

Comment: Also what about the quality of reviews from someone who *isn't* gaming the system (OP for QC purposes) vs someone who is merely doing it for the badge and then quits? :) I think the system needs something for those people who put in the extra time and effort for the good of the community and not themselves.

Comment: About crap reviews. The point is that they ***quit*** after reaching 1k, because they only did it for the badge.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: For reviews that are behind (such as the close queue) the limit already has been raised to 40. For the suggested edit queue, we are doing just fine on SO, there isn't a real backlog, is there?

Comment: This answer looks good to me. +1

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I am not certain that crap reviewers actually quit reviewing after the badge, myself. Some crap reviewers are just crap reviewers, not because they wanted the badge but because they lack judgement. I see no reason to lift the cap for those either.

Comment: There are currently >47K outstanding items in the closevote review queue. At a rate of 20/day/user we will never get to the bottom of this, so I don't think this answer stands up to an examination. At least the limit should be increased for the close vote queue (which is always very high)

Comment: @DaveRandom That figure was about [55k in October of last year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163830/how-slow-is-the-close-votes-queue-being-processed-and-how-large-should-it-get-d/163837#163837).

Comment: @Bart: So at this rate it'll take us about **2 years** to completely review them all. And that's assuming no raise in crap questions would occur, which is something we can't promise.

Comment: So it's taken us 4 months to reduce it by 8K? Couldn't we at least raise the limit while the queue is purged? Come to that, I get 50 close votes per day, it would make sense if I can use them all in the review queue.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha 2 years is not all that long. And why not somehow get more hands to do the work instead?

Comment: @DaveRandom The closevote review queue limit is 40/user/day. So. That leaves you 10 close votes to do with as you please, when you stumble on questions that should be closed that aren't hidden in the unfathomably huge heap of the review queue. =)

Comment: @DaveRandom: note that *new close votes* are added to that queue every single day (unfortunately). On Programmers I regularly get to use my 20 close-vote reviews in a day, and there is no backlog there.  99% of that huge backlog in SO predates the review queue, so they are old questions, that obviously haven't been that high a priority before. New close votes get dealt with quickly. Since the backlog is being whittled away steadily, I don't think there is a reason to increase the limit, let alone dismiss the limit altogether (for gold badge earners or otherwise).