# Editing a post with a pending edit after already reviewing 20 edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, review, suggested-edits

*Note: Somewhat related to [Unable to edit posts with pending edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78065/unable-to-edit-posts-with-pending-edits).*

As a Suggested Edits queue reviewer, it's frustrating when reviewing a question that requires an edit, and going to edit only to find that you're not able due to a pending edit.

Of course, if I hadn't used up all 20 edits from the queue in this day, I would be able to either **Accept** or **Improve** the edit with my own changes. However when all of the edits are used up, this leaves no option but to move on which is fairly limiting. It's made worse when the pending edit doesn't actually address what you wanted to change.

[image: Blocking screen that I am referring to]

Is there any way to bypass this limitation? (That is, of course, without refreshing endlessly waiting for the edit to be approved or rejected to make your own)

Comment: The suggested edit queue is a fast one, so most of the time the wait is not that long.  Just be patient and have a look outside.

Comment: Also related: [suggested edits after limit of 20 runs out - how to proceed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157354/suggested-edits-after-limit-of-20-runs-out-how-to-proceed)

Comment: Suggestion - Maybe just give us like the ability to review another 10 outside of the queue, kind of like close votes.

Answer (score 6):

I got stuck by this today, on this question: [trying to convert a simple hashtable to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712018) (that's the old title, which I hope has been changed by now).

I don't think, after reviewing 20 questions in the queue, I should be able to **accept** an edit, but I certainly should be able to **improve** or **reject and improve** an edit, especially when I think the suggestion is insufficient. In this case, the suggestion did nothing about the title and left some other issues to be desired.

I also don't think we should be able to count these questions towards our suggested edit queue badges, obviously.

Please give us the ability to improve these questions. Why actively block users from improving questions for any reason?

Comment: "_that's the old title, which I hope has been changed by now_" Now it has thanks to the Meta effect.

Answer (score 2):

For now, use [a workaround userscript that allows direct editing](https://stackapps.com/questions/4274/force-edit-suggested-reviews). This is unfortunately unable to Improve Edits: it will always Reject with a conflict. (It doesn't count toward review badges.)

Comment: This is helpful I guess, but you've got to admit it's a pretty crap solution.

Comment: @durron597: Oh, sure. But it is the best we've got right until this is implemented.

Comment: @DonaldDuck: That's the only thing the script adds; I don't know of any reason for it to fail, and haven't observed it to do so.