# Bug when reaching pending edit limit while doing review tasks

Tags: bug, review, edits

First of all, this is NOT a duplicate of [Editing a post with a pending edit after already reviewing 20 edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164381/editing-a-post-with-a-pending-edit-after-already-reviewing-20-edits).

Sometimes, I contribute to the community proposing some edits, and then I keep on contributing performing review tasks.

The bug I've seen is that the "pending edit limit" popup is NOT shown in case I'm in the review tasks UI.

To understand why the 'edit' menu seems broken, I open the regarded reviewed question in another tab, and I click on the same 'edit' menu, and here, in the usual Question UI, I see the popup explaining I have too much 'pending edit proposal'.