# Asked to review instead of edit, but cannot because temporary review quota reached

Tags: support, review, edits, diff

I clicked Edit to edit a question (to add tags). I was told to instead review a pending edit for the question. But I had already reviewed the maximum number of edits for that category for now, so it was *impossible* to review them. IOW, I was shown the diff for a proposed edit, but I could not accept it or reject it or edit the question further.

What's the point of showing me the diff and asking me to review a pending edit, if I am prevented from actually doing that?  Am I missing something, or is there perhaps a bug here?

Comment: Possible duplicates - [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164381/editing-a-post-with-a-pending-edit-after-already-reviewing-20-edits), [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157354/suggested-edits-after-limit-of-20-runs-out-how-to-proceed).